# How much external storage can be added to a elasticsearch node

Tags: elasticsearch, digital-ocean, solid-state-drive, server-configuration

I am try setting up a single node cluster and node specifications are

- 4GB RAM
- 2 CPU
- 60 GB internal hard disk.

By using this configuration how much external storage disk (SSD) I can add for elasticsearch data storage without compromising the indexing and searching performance?

Can anyone suggest me the maximum storage configuration? Because external storage is cheaper compared to the higher volume nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[How much external storage can be added to an elastic node?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-much-external-storage-can-be-added-to-a-elastic-node/63684) 
I have asked this question in the elasticsearch forum too. And I got the response really fast. Still, the forum discussion is going. If your scenario is same, you might get some information there.